# How destructor called when Garbage Collection is in action [.NET]?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I was experimenting with garbage collector and found strange count `iCnt` on `destructor` call.
Here is the Code:-

```
public class MyClass
{
    static long iCnt;
    public MyClass()
    {
        iCnt++;
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        iCnt--;
    }
    static public string ObjectCount
    {
        get
        {
            return iCnt.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Below code is to create objects, delete objects(De-refernce by assigning to `null`) and explicitly call `GC.Collect()`.
I have having all it in a Win Form which has `Timer` of `interval = 100`, timer show the current count of `iCnt`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MyClass[] Objs;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnCreateObjects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Objs = new MyClass[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Objs[i] = new MyClass();
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = MyClass.ObjectCount;
    }
    private void btnDeleteObjects_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Objs[i] = null;
        }
    }

    private void btnInvokeGC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Now create the object until the garbage collector is called automatically(for me it took 24 clicks). Again repeat this action.

I saw this `iCnt` < 1000. which keeps me confusing how the destructor called in this scenario.
when `iCnt` < 1000, click on delete object which deference the `Objs[1000]`. Then call `GC.Collect()` which makes count of `iCnt` < 0 (very strange).

Can anybody explain me this behavior. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit it for clarify. Things like "I saw this `iCnt < 1000`" aren't clear in terms of what's going on. It would be helpful if you could write a *console* application showing what you're interested in, as then it's easier for everyone else to run it. Also note that your counter isn't thread-safe at the moment - you should be using `Interlocked.Increment` and `Interlocked.Decrement`.

Comment: @DanielA.White: It depends on which spec you read. The MS C# spec still calls it a destructor.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, just i ran it after using `Interlocked.Increment` and `Interlocked.Decrement` and guess what i resolved it my self.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty classic threading bug.  The destructor runs on the finalizer thread, asynchronously from the thread that increments the count.  You need to use Interlocked.Increment() and Decrement() to do this safely.  Or use the *lock* keyword.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean the constructors are still getting called when the GC collects? I doubt that's the case for 1000 small objects.

Comment: @les - The finalizer thread runs after a collection.  Writing finalizers that have a side effect is in general a bad idea.

Comment: Well yeah, obviously. But I don't see it happening in this example.

Comment: That's a common problem with threading race bugs, they never repro well.

Comment: After making my count variable thread safe, the count is consistent and is multiple of 1000 every time. WoW I learn classic implementation for threading bug in GC. Thanks @HansPassant

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really need to do is to employ the "using" statement.  Like this:

using(foo = new bar()) { ... code ... }

With using you can be certain that the dispose event will occur when the code terminates, even if it throws an exception.  In the situation that you've described the C# garbage collector decides when to trigger the dispose event (which is what calls your destructor).  So you can have long periods when objects are sitting around with no references to them but not disposed just the same.

Comment: You may want to mention that `using` would require that his class implements `IDisposable` and that his finalizer logic should be moved into the Dispose method.